# dask - applying map_partitions to clean text returns "'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'"

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to lower case my training data using `map_partition`. It keeps returning me an error when trying to print the head of the dataframe. What am I missing to apply my clean function

```
def clean_text(df):
    df['X_trn'] = df['X_trn'].apply(lambda text:text.lower())
    return df

training = training.map_partitions(clean_text, meta=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `meta` option you specified `object`, so dask is expecting each partition to map to an object. The function `clean_text` returns `pandas.DataFrame`, so the `meta` option should be of the same type:

```py
meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=training.columns)
```

Also, just in case you are using that function in the code, note that many common string operations are possible with the vectorized `Series.str` functions, for example `df['X_trn'].str.lower()` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)).

Comment: Doing so returns a type "dask.dataframe.core.Index" which is not want one would ideally want

Comment: That is odd, are you using the same function as in your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to use below one:

```
df['X_trn'] = df['X_trn'].str.lower()
```

Incase, if you have to use map_partitions, try below one - this will work parallel across your data-frame partitions:

```
df['X_trn'] = df['X_trn'].map_partitions(lambda x: x.lower())
```